# Why does Resharper find fault with its own fix?

Tags: razor, resharper

I had this code:

```
report_parms =
{
     GUID: @Model.GUID;
        . . .
```

...and Resharper suggested I change it to this:

```
GUID: "@if (Model != null)
       {
           @Model.GUID
       }
",
```

...but then Resharper said, "*Unexpected token", but it's suggested fix is "Replace double-quote string with single-quoted string"* on subsequent check to "Find Code Issues"

Is Resharper confused by Razor syntax, or...???

Comment: You definitely don't need the quotes around the if block there. Can't say why Resharper thought you might, but sometimes it does things like that.

Comment: Clay, please file issue at [tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP) with full text of example.

Comment: I tried, but I got, "The server is temporary overloaded, please try again later.

Sorry for the inconvenience." If I remember later, I will, but really there's nothing to add there besides what has already been shown above.